# Playing 4K video in browser

Tags: flash, video, browser

What's the best solution for playing 4K video in browser? I also want to translate and scale it.

I tried HTML5,FlowPlayer and Quicktime, didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube do this using flash.

4k in streaming is a joke most of the time, if you want quality, increase bitrate on 1080p. It will give you better results than the same bitrate on 4k.

Comment: No streaming. Will be playing local content. Can I still use youtube plaeyr?

Comment: You can use any flash based player that support this resolution. But you will have to reencode files in mpeg4.